# List all active subscription in PayPal

Tags: c#, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

We are implementing the PayPal Rest API in dotnet application. Is there any API available to list all the currently active subscriptions in an account?

Comment: Would https://developer.paypal.com/braintree/docs/reference/request/subscription/search help u? You have there status param and you should check for Active

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. I am not planning to connect braintree with my paypal account. SO I am searching for any API from the paypal itself to get all the list of subscriptions. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Use https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/#plans_list but this will return all the plans and then you have to filter them base on "status": "ACTIVE".

Answer (score 0):

There is no API method to list active subscriptions. When working with subscriptions keep your own records, in your own database. Register a webhook listener for the PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED event to keep your valid through period up to date based on each payment.

There is a web interface in the PayPal account that lists subscriptions, https://www.paypal.com/billing/subscriptions